# Need help displaying an image with flutter/dart

Tags: image, flutter, dart

I am brand new here and have been looking around for a while but can't seem to find anything related to what I'm trying to do.
I have created a simple quiz app and I have collected the users' answers and scored them. I have worked out how to display text to the user based on their score but am now trying to work on how to display an image that is based on their result. I have made a separate widget for the image(s) but am having trouble implementing it into my "results" widget. Is this the best way to go for something like this? Using a Boolean then redirecting them to the specified widget, or would it be better to display the image using a different way in the results widget itself. Any tips or advice as I'm extremely new to all of this, even links to text tutorials or videos would be really appreciated. Apologies if this is already out there somewhere I probably just didn't look hard enough.

Answer (score 0):

You can load a "RootWidget" which decides what image to show.

Your Score View:

```
Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    Text(
     'YourScore',
    ),
    ImageChooser(
      score
    ),
  ],
),
```

ImageChooser build Method:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if(widget.score > 10) {
        return Image(YOUR_IMAGE_1);
    } else {
        return Image(YOUR_IMAGE_2);
    }      
}
```

EDIT: You need to pass the score in the constructor of the StatefulWidget

Comment: Appreciate it, will give this a shot tonight